# pass line-buffered output from bash into a node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I need to send an ongoing line-buffered output from a terminal command on a Pi which fits this format:

```
/1 12:33:44:55:66:77:88 33 a string
/2 33:55:77:oo:55:jj:rr -10 another string
```

/3, /4, etc., to replace the "new log line" string in this node.js script from https://github.com/yaronn/blessed-contrib

```
    var blessed = require('blessed')
  , contrib = require('../')
  , screen = blessed.screen()
  , log = contrib.log(
      { fg: "green"
      , label: 'Server Log'      
      , height: "20%"
      , tags: true      
      , border: {type: "line", fg: "cyan"} })

screen.append(log)

var i = 0
setInterval(function() {log.log("new {red-fg}log{/red-fg} line " + i++)}, 500)

screen.render()
```

My js knowledge is basic and this is my first time playing with node, but this will do exactly what I need it to do if I can set the output from the terminal command to display in this rolling log.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.